# How can I calculate transition probabilities trial by trial?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, probability

I have a list converted to pandas dataframe consisting of zeros and ones. The first 20 trials of the `df['response']` are called block 1 and next 20 are called block 2. Each row indicates a trial, so there are in total 40 trials. I want to know the pairwise probability or the transition probabilities of 5 steps. For example, what is the probability of a transition from 0 to 0, 0 to 1, 1 to 0 and 1 to 1 in the first 5 steps and how it does it change for the all blocks? I want to understand how the trend changes from block 1 to block 2 but trialwise.

I tried this, but how should I do it trial by trial:

```
df['response'] = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1.....]
sc = df['response'].tolist()
sc = [x for x in sc if not np.isnan(x)]


def transition_matrix(transitions):
    n = 1 + int(max(transitions))  # Number of states
    M = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]

    for (i, j) in zip(transitions, transitions[1:]):
        M[int(i)][int(j)] += 1

    for row in M:
        s = sum(row)
        if s > 0:
            row[:] = [f / s for f in row]
    return M

trial_ranges = [(0, 21), (21, 41), (41, 61), (61, 81)]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(trial_ranges), figsize=(16, 6))

for i, trial_range in enumerate(trial_ranges):
    start, end = trial_range
    sub_sc = sc[start:end]
    transition_matrix_sub = transition_matrix(sub_sc)

    sns.heatmap(transition_matrix_sub, annot=True, fmt=".2f", cmap="YlGnBu", ax=axes[i])
    axes[i].set_xlabel('To State')
    axes[i].set_ylabel('From State')
    axes[i].set_title(f'Transition Probabilities (Trials {start}-{end})')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Reserve tag [Python-3.x] for versioning issues.. For this question, tag [Python] applies instead.

Comment: As mentioned already, the first two trials would act as block 1 and the next as block two, there is nothing much to it other than this!, i will edit the question saying first 20 trials of df['response'] are block1 and next 20 are block 2.

Comment: I left for a while. Nice Numpy code! However, 19 digits provided are still not enough "blocks" for a [mre]. Why have us come up with mock-up data when you could provide it? Also nothing huge but your code fails at line 1 because dataframe doesn't exist. Then you turn it into an array right away. Looks like you could spare the df part, as far as this post is concerned

Comment: This is already trailwise, isn't it? Right now 1 trial inclides 20 steps, which you have called a block. You say you would like groups of 5 steps? Aside from the fact that 5 isn't going to be enough to calculate a meaningfull probability matrix, have you tried to modify the numbers in `trial_ranges  = (0, 21), (21, 41), (41, 61), (61, 81)`? I am afraid I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, I would say that the approach you have is good, but you could make some modifications and improvements such as data consistency:

1. It looks like you have a NaN value in your data and you remove it afterwards.
2. You want to make sure that there are no other unexpected values or missing data.
3. You want to make sure that each range is corresponding to a unique set of trials.
4. You also want to define the function for transition probabilities. This means that instead of creating the transition matrix directly, you define a separate function that calculates the transition probabilities for a given number of steps. Doing this would make your code more modular and easier to understand.
5. You could also create a separate function for plotting the transition matrix to avoid repetitive code.
6. You could utilize the functions you created in a loop for different trial ranges including even overlapping trial ranges.

Again, this is just what I thought. However, I could be wrong too. Let me know if I can help you out!

Comment: Hi thanks for the great suggestions, will try implementing.however, I am not sure how to edit with the range of calculating first 5 trials and then next 5 and so on!